# how to run jar file with spring.config.location option in command line

Tags: spring, jar, configuration

I wanna run my jar file from the command line. If I run it with Intellij IDEA - all works fine.

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:54124,suspend=y,server=n -Dcom.sun.management.config.file=/Users/admin/Desktop/src/config_local/ngs/ngpd/jmx.properties -Dngpd.conf=/Users/admin/Desktop/src/config_local/ngs/ngpd/ngpd.properties -javaagent:/Users/admin/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar -jar /Users/admin/IdeaProjects/GameServer-JARs/src/jars/ngs-demo-platform-server-2.19.2.b4.jar —spring.config.location=classpath:/ngpd.yaml,file:/Users/admin/Desktop/src/config_local/ngs/ngpd/ngpd.yaml

But when I trying run it in the command line it fails:

java -Dcom.sun.management.config.file=/Users/admin/Desktop/src/config_local/ngs/ngpd/jmx.properties -Dngpd.conf=/Users/admin/Desktop/src/config_local/ngs/ngpd/ngpd.properties -jar /Users/admin/IdeaProjects/GameServer-JARs/src/jars/ngs-demo-platform-server-2.19.2.b4.jar —spring.config.location=classpath:/ngpd.yaml,file:/Users/admin/Desktop/src/config_local/ngs/ngpd/ngpd.yaml

I cannot properly pass to the command argument —spring.config.location.
I have Error:

AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext:551 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gameVerificationMXBean' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/admin/IdeaProjects/GameServer-JARs/src/jars/ngs-demo-platform-server-2.19.2.b4.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ngs/dp/server/jmx/GameVerificationMXBean.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gameVerificationServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'demo.gamesVerification.requestAttemptsCount' in value "${demo.gamesVerification.requestAttemptsCount}"

What am I doing wrong? Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

All I need was:

java -Dspring.config.location=classpath:/ngpd.yaml,file:/Users/admin/Desktop/src/config_local/ngs/ngpd/ngpd.yaml -Dcom.sun.management.config.file=/Users/admin/Desktop/src/config_local/ngs/ngpd/jmx.properties -Dngpd.conf=/Users/admin/Desktop/src/config_local/ngs/ngpd/ngpd.properties -jar /Users/admin/IdeaProjects/GameServer-JARs/src/jars/ngs-demo-platform-server-2.19.2.b4.jar